# How to subtract CloudWatch Sum Statisitic with 1hr period from datapoint 24 hours in the past?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to monitor the change in traffic on our application between days. We currently have a metric plotting the sum of 1 day between sequential days, however this comes with a 24 hr delay as we need to wait for the current day's traffic.

I'm trying to figure out a way to produce a graph that sums data over a 1hr period, and subtracts the same datapoint from 24 hrs in the past.

I can't figure out a way to do this with metric math. Anyone have any suggestions? Preferably within AWS, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an [export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html) of the CloudWatch logs into S3.  Then you can use [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html) to write SQL queries of arbitrary complexity, which you can then visualize using [QuickSight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/create-a-data-set-athena.html).

It is not going to be as near-realtime as CloudWatch: there may be about a few hours' lag in S3 export.  For a real-time solution, you may consider streaming logs into a [Kinesis Datastream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html) and then create a custom Lambda to process the logs and push them into a QuickSight dataset.